# Deregister a CSS file that comes with a plugin

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

WPML plugin comes with its own CSS file. I want to get rid of all the CSS it contains, so I put everything between `/* */`. However I'll have to do that again when I'll update the plugin. Is there a way to "unload" a CSS file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wp_dequeue_style function, with a wp_enqueue_script hook with priority higher than WPML's wp_enqueue_script hook. Put the following code into your functions.php:

```
function dequeue_wpml_styles(){
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wmpl_style_handle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_wpml_styles', 20 );
```

REPLACE 'wmpl_style_handle' with the handle WPML registers/enqueues the style.

**UPDATE**: I have just had a look into WPML and it looks that it doesn't use wp_enqueue_script to include language-selector.css, But the good news is that there is a constant which you can set to prevent loading of the language selector styles. Just add the line below to your functions.php:

```
define('ICL_DONT_LOAD_LANGUAGE_SELECTOR_CSS', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this message: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'http://mysite.com/.../plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/language-selector.css' not found or invalid function name in /home/blabla/public_html/mysite.com/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 403

Comment: Please make sure the call back name you register with add_action matches your function name. In the sample above, it's 'dequeue_wpml_styles'.
And where did you exactly put the code?

Comment: I added it at the end of functions.php. Here's the exact line of code I put: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', plugins_url('/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/language-selector.css', __FILE__), 20 );

Comment: @drake035 See my updated answer above.

Comment: thanks a lot, works perfectly! One more thing: how did you find so quickly that WPML provides a constant for this?

Comment: @drake035 Search for language-selector.css in the source code and then you will see in the first line of icl_lang_sel_nav_css function it checks for this constant.
See WPML Coding API for more constants: http://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/#disable_css_js